# PayPal Adaptive Payments - Invite Only?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use Paypal Adaptive Payments to implement a P2P marketplace - buyer and seller transact and we take a small commission. It seems like Adaptive Payments is what i want to use, but it's invite only. Is there another PayPal API workaround that works?

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments is categorized with a few options, Kindly refer below

1. Chained Payments - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/
2. Parallel Payments( Express Checkout)-https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/

Answer (score 0):

Till 2 years ago you could ask paypal for an app id but this program as closed and now those APIs are deprecated and available only for those who had active integrations.